# URLRequest.addValue() causes SwiftUI calendar to revert date

Tags: swift, datepicker, swiftui, urlrequest

The function below is called every 3 seconds and looks like:

```
func fetchItems(){
    let url = URL(string: itemUrl)!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("Item \(self.item)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: parseJasonObject)
    task.resume()
}

func parseJasonObject(data: Data?, urlResponse: URLResponse?, error: Error?){
    guard error == nil else {
        print("error: \(error!)")
        return
    }
    
    guard let content = data else{
        print("No data")
        return
    }
    
    if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode([itemdata]?.self, from: content) {
        // we have good data – go back to the main thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.items = decodedResponse
            self.dataHasLoaded = true // state variable that determines whether or not data has been loaded
        }
    }
    
}
```

If I comment out the request.addValue() line, it causes the calendar to not exhibit a strange glitch where if you navigate the calendar to a new month or different date, when the above function runs, it reverts the calendar to it's starting screen (showing the current date). The calendar looks like:

```
@State private var selectedStartTime = Date()
let timer = Timer.publish(every: 3, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

HStack {
    Spacer()
    DatePicker("", selection: self.$selectedStartTime, in: Date()...) //where self.$selectedStartTime is just a variable that is defined by the date/time the user selected
        .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
    Spacer()
}
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ns9XXgrmiZk

As you can see, if I go to another month without selecting a date in that month, when the fetchEvents() function is run--it runs every 3 seconds inside an onReceive--it causes the calendar to go back to the currently selected day. If I select a new day in a different month, this is a non-issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: needed minimal reproducible example

Comment: @Asperi It's hard to make it completely a minimal reproducible example because you guys are obviously not connected to the backend but I added some stuff that should help figure out what's going on...thanks again in advance!

Comment: where are these two values used?
self.items = decodedResponse
            self.dataHasLoaded = true //

Comment: @JIEWANG it's used in a ton of different places....but it is also used in the onReceive function...could that be the source of the error?

Comment: @nickcoding it's possible, can you put all your code related to your "calendar view"?